# Hibernate ScrollableResults OutOfMemory

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 7500 rows in Table User in MySQL db,VM option : -Xmx8m and some code below :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select u from User u");
        ScrollableResults resultSet = query.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE).setReadOnly(true).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

        int i = 0;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            User o = (User) resultSet.get(0);   
            System.out.println(o.getId());    
            i++;
            if (i % 50 == 0) {
                session.clear();
            }
        }
        resultSet.close();
```

But unfortunately I have this output in my console :
...
5745
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

But I do not understand why?? Integer.MIN_VALUE - serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row. Maybe I have a problem cause ScrollableResults stored in memory and 8m of heap is not enough ??

Answer (score 0):

When memory usage exceeds beyond Xmx configuration.  JVM may try to collect garbage to free up enough memory and garbage collector is taking an excessive amount of time.we get out of memory exception "`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.`".You have to increase the (Xmx) maximum amount of JVM memory or just remove the JVM flag to use default allocation. (Assumed you have enough physical memory)

[Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

[Troubleshooting Memory Leaks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks.html)

```
C:\>java -X

    -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
    -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size

The -X options are non-standard and subject to change without notice.
```

As this is small set of data (7500) mysql JDBC driver should be able to handle this. Note that last batch of records will not be cleared from session. Even though from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html in ResultSet Section :

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in
>   memory.In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate and,
>   due to the design of the MySQL network protocol, is easier to
>   implement. If you are working with ResultSets that have a large number
>   of rows or large values and cannot allocate heap space in your JVM for
>   the memory required, you can tell the driver to stream the results
>   back one row at a time.

You have to check hibernate and JDBC drive versions.

Comment: OK. I have set 8m of heap size specially because I want to check ScrollaleResultset and does it really may handle huge data. I didnt get explanation why OutOfMemory is occured. Am I right that ScrollableResult store some data??

Comment: You could generate memory dump with "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" jvm option and analysis memory dump  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks.html

Comment: I have done it, and I got this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388025/hibernate-scrollableresultset-unexpected-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps somebody.

What helped me:

```
ScrollableResults<T> results = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFetchSize(100).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```