# Hibernate ScrollableResultSet unexpected OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, scrollableresults

I have Postgres DB, 7500 rows in Client table, -Xmx8m.

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select c from Client c");
ScrollableResults resultSet = query.setFetchSize(50).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    int i = 0;

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Client client = (Client) resultSet.get(0);
        System.out.println(client.getId());
        i++;
        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            session.clear();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
    session.clear();
    resultSet.close();
```

When I run my app I got this :
....
4188
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Then I have set -Xmx1024m and run jvisualvm and got this -

[image]
Why I got a lot of strings ???? Who can explain why OutOfMemory is occurred ?

Answer (score -2):

Since its a stateful session. Objects are not evicted. In addition to `session.clear()` do call  `session.flush()`. Since its stateful session all objects will be in memory due to hibernate first level cache.

Otherwise use stateless session

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html